# How to disable visual theme of executables

Tags: themes

Is there a way to disable the visual theme of windows, when running some executables? (not manually, but with some ini or manifest file, or any other option)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the executable. Is it a managed exe? i.e uses the .NET Framework? Is it a Java Executable (*.JAR)? Does it use some toolkit that does not depend on the Windows Visual theme, but only **emulates** it? e.g Java Swing or GTK?

I think in GTK you can change the Visual Theme quite easily using the `Gtk resource file`. In Java Swing you can send the theme as a command-line argument. In .NET, I think you may be able to change it with a manifest file, but I don't know for sure.